# Two step SQL Statement in only one SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform a efficent SQL-statement, but I don't know how to build the query correctly.

I have the following tables:

```
t1(user_id, test_id, module_id, save_id)
t2(save_id, answer_id)
```

save_id from t2 is a foreign key for t1.save_id

So some entries:

```
T1:
1, 3, 4, 40
1, 5, 33, 80
2, 5, 33, 90
2, 6, 7, 82
T2: 
80, A2
```

So now I want all user_ids and the value of the answer_id, which have an entry for test_id=3 and module_id=4 (only these users!). The value of the searched answer is always from test_id=5 and module_id=33, the only variable thing is the save_id of the answer. I think, this can be linked through a normal JOIN, but how can I isolate only users, for who a entry exists with test_id=3 and module_id=4. In this example I only want to get user 1, user 2 is not relevant, because there is noch entry for test_id=3 and module_id=4.

Comment: Just do the join and add your where clause. Thats the whole magic ;)

Comment: Well I think Andreas is a novice in SQL. Andreas, search for INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN on Google and you'll get what you want. As say Ben, Thats the whole magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a where clause to your join `Select * FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id WHERE t1.foo = "bar" AND t2.bar = "foo";`

Comment: I dont think this is the answer. If I perform a INNER JOIN, I would map each user to his answer_id in T2. After this, I have ALL users, when I compute WHERE t1.test_id='5' AND t1.answer_id='33', I get ALL users again, but I only want the users, who has also an entry for t1.test_id='3' AND t1.module_id='4' (the answer here is irrelevant, so no additional join). Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 t1.user_id
 ,t2.answer_id
 FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.save_id=t2.save_id
 WHERE t1.test_id=3
 AND t1.module_id=4;
```